# how to fix JavaFX Application Thread errors

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem with JavaFX application thread.

The code is related to the employee search field:

```
public class ShowEmployees {
@FXML
private TableView<EmployeeTO> tableView;
@FXML
private TextField filterField;

private ObservableList<EmployeeTO> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<EmployeeTO> filteredData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public ShowEmployees(){
    try {
        PersonDA<EmployeeTO> personDA = new PersonDA();
        observableList.addAll(personDA.select());
        filteredData.addAll(observableList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    observableList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<EmployeeTO>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends EmployeeTO> change) {
            updateFilteredData();
        }
    });
}

@FXML
private void initialize() {

/////////////////
    TableColumn personnelCode = new TableColumn("personal code");
    personnelCode.setMinWidth(100);
    personnelCode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EmployeeTO ,Integer >("personnelCode"));
/////////////////
    TableColumn name = new TableColumn("name");
    name.setMinWidth(100);
    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EmployeeTO ,String >("name"));
/////////////////
    TableColumn lastname = new TableColumn("lastName");
    lastname.setMinWidth(100);
    lastname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EmployeeTO ,String >("lastName"));

    tableView.getColumns().addAll(personnelCode,name,lastname);
    tableView.setItems(filteredData);

    // Listen for text changes in the filter text field
    filterField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,String oldValue, String newValue) {
            updateFilteredData();
        }
    });
}
private void updateFilteredData() {
    filteredData.clear();

    for (EmployeeTO p : observableList) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
        if (matchesFilter(p)) {
            filteredData.add(p);
        }
    });
    }

    // Must re-sort table after items changed
    reapplyTableSortOrder();
}
private boolean matchesFilter(EmployeeTO employee) {
    String filterString = filterField.getText();
    if (filterString == null || filterString.isEmpty()) {
        // No filter --> Add all.
        return true;
    }

    String lowerCaseFilterString = filterString.toLowerCase();
    if (employee.getName().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilterString) != -1) {
        return true;
    } else if (employee.getLastName().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilterString) != -1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false; // Does not match
}

private void reapplyTableSortOrder() {
    ArrayList<TableColumn<EmployeeTO, ?>> sortOrder = new ArrayList<>(tableView.getSortOrder());
    tableView.getSortOrder().clear();
    tableView.getSortOrder().addAll(sortOrder);
}
```

}

The following error occurs when you search on the list of employees.

Errors :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at controller.ShowEmployees.matchesFilter(ShowEmployees.java:131)
at controller.ShowEmployees.lambda$updateFilteredData$0(ShowEmployees.java:106)
at controller.ShowEmployees$$Lambda$244/1338548772.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$163(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1037924535.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$164(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/786335548.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$140(WinApplication.java:100)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/705897616.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can somebody help me to fix this Errors??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As the stack trace says, an object on line 131 of ShowEmployees.java is null.  Which is line 131?

Comment: line 131 : if (employee.getName().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilterString) != -1)

Comment: line 106 : if (matchesFilter(p))

Comment: I would hazard a guess that when line 131 is run, `employee` is null.  Check where this is coming from.  (i.e. observableList has at least one null value?)

Comment: This has nothing to do with threading. You are not even using multiple threads here. Also, why don't you use the predefined [`FilteredList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html), instead of trying to build your own implementation?